# What causes a 40 second delay when running an executable using Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm running an executable on the local file system using Process.Start() from an ASP.NET web application. This runs correctly and does what I expect it to, the problem is that it takes around 40 seconds before the exe starts after Process.Start() has been called.

When I run the exe from the command line it only takes a few seconds to complete its work.

Does anyone know what is causing this long delay when I use Process.Start()?

Thanks in advance!

Robert

Comment: Seems odd... what are you starting?  If you check the process list, do you see the process running as called and it just doesn't do anything for 40 seconds?  I suspect there is an issue running whatever process you are running from a different account.

Comment: Sounds dangerous to launch an application from an ASP.NET webpage. I could imagine that the 40 seconds are to set up an desktop environment for the user that is being used to start the application. On the other hand, only by profiling, you could be sure what the cause is.

Comment: @Brad I'm running the wkhtmltopdf PDF generator on a secured website. I can see the program running in the task manager straight away, but it doesn't actually do any work for around 40 seconds then executes as expected.

Comment: @Uwe I take your point about security issues. My plan is to run the process with an account with as few permissions as possible. The functionality will not be publicly available and only admin users of the site will be able to run it.

Comment: @Robert Dougan: What happens when you run wkhtmltopdf from the command line? Does this also take 40 sec? If so, the problem may be that the page you're converting to PDF is taking too long to load (some JS scripts are rather notorious in this regard - *cough* GA *cough*)

Comment: The program may be trying to access the internet and give up after 40 secs. You could use a monitoring tool to check. Maybe a commercial thing or a check for updates.

Comment: @Robert, if you see the process executing right away, then there is no problem with your Process.Start.  The issue is something with wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @Piskvor If I run it from the command line it completes in work in a few seconds. I'm also running the tool with an option to disable JavaScript on the target page.

Comment: One suggestion: use the overload that takes a `ProcessStartInfo` and try setting `UseShellExecute` property to false.

Comment: @Paul I tried this but no effect sadly, thanks for the hint though.

Comment: In which case all I can suggest is getting out the debugger. 40 seconds does smell like a timeout though.

Comment: @Robert: Good to hear that you solved your problem!  You can actually post your solution as an answer (and accept it) instead of posting it as an update to the question. That should be clearer to anyone coming by later.

Comment: @Justin Good idea, I didn't actually know you could do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to have been caused by trying to run the exe using the web application's default worker process account. I have updated the ProcessStartInfo to use a pre defined user account with restricted permissions on the server and the exe ran almost instantly.